# ImportError with PySide6/shiboken6

Tags: python, pyside6

I'm trying to get PySide6 to run in Python 3.8.0. Installation went fine:

```
C:\>pip install pyside6
Collecting pyside6
  Using cached PySide6-6.0.0-6.0.0-cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-none-win_amd64.whl (62.4 MB)
Collecting shiboken6==6.0.0
  Using cached shiboken6-6.0.0-6.0.0-cp36.cp37.cp38.cp39-none-win_amd64.whl (2.3 MB)
Installing collected packages: shiboken6, pyside6
Successfully installed pyside6-6.0.0 shiboken6-6.0.0
```

but i'm hit with an import error:

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PySide6
PySide6/__init__.py: Unable to import shiboken6 from , C:\Python38\python38.zip, C:\Python38\DLLs, C:\Python38\lib, C:\Python38, C:\Python38\lib\site-packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySide6\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    _setupQtDirectories()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PySide6\__init__.py", line 57, in _setupQtDirectories
    import shiboken6
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\shiboken6\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .shiboken6 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shiboken6: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What did i do wrong?

I don't believe you did anything wrong.

I think this was a known bug in `shiboken6` versions `<=6.0.0`. It was reported partly in the `PySide` bug tracker: [PYSIDE-932](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-932).

The issue appeared to be that they were attempting to import from a `zip` file. From the comments in version `6.3.0` of `shiboken6.__init__`:

```py
# PYSIDE-932: Python 2 cannot import 'zipfile' for embedding while being imported, itself.
# We simply pre-load all imports for the signature extension.
# Also, PyInstaller seems not always to be reliable in finding modules.
# We explicitly import everything that is needed:
```

The comment says `Python 2 cannot import`, but it should read `PySide2 cannot import` because the issue came from `Python 3.6` using `PySide 2`.

[The Qt Docs](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/Considerations#ImportError:_DLL_load_failed:_The_specified_module_could_not_be_found) mention using a newer version of `virtualenv` to fix this problem, but I do not believe `virtualenv` is the culprit. Moreover, the latest `Python 3` versions ship with and use `venv`. Instead, I believe this was an issue with importing `zip` files. It may have been resolved when Barry Warsaw/Brett Cannon and their team introduced `importlib.resources` in newer versions of `Python 3`, which can particularly help with zip files.

See their talk here:

[Barry Warsaw - Get your resources faster, with importlib.resources - PyCon 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsGFU2qh73E)

Ultimately, I believe this was resolved in the latest version of `shiboken6` (i.e. `6.3.0`).

Give that a try and see if that works.